# Does including classes that you don't use have impact on performance?

Tags: php, class

like

```
require "class.a.php";
require "class.b.php";
require "class.c.php";

class main{
 function main(){
   if(condition_is_met(){
      $this->something = new A();
   }else{
      $this->something = new B();
   }
 } 

}
```

Should the files be included in the condition check with require_once, and not all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only performance it should effect is the time to parse it, but I think that is preferred over complicated include logic hidden midway inside of your file. Not to mention that if you put the require inside of the if statement it is like you inserted that file's text inside of that if statement, which isn't right (and may not work).

Can anyone tell me if you can declare a class inside of a function/if statement?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has to open the file and parse it so it has some impact. For a few files I wouldn't worry about it but it can get out of hand as your files increase. That's why there's **autoload**, which allows you to load class files only when needed, without having a long list of requires at the top of your files:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Also take a look at `spl_autoload_register`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Does PHP keep pre-compiled versions of the source files cached or are files parsed and compiled with every request?

Comment: And use the [PSR-0 file naming convention](https://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1) to minimize the number of auto loaders (if all your libs use PSR-0 you have only one autoloader)

Comment: @Tomalak, this is opcode caches' main purpose (see [APC](http://pecl.php.net/packages/APC)). Without them PHP compiles the same files again on each request.

Comment: @arnaud576875: I take that as a "no" with regard to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. In the current code, I think all of the file(s) will get included, whether you use (declare variable of these classes) them or not. If you wan't to not load the class(es) you will not use, you can use the `__autoload()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: And use the [PSR-0 file naming convention](https://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1) to minimize the number of auto loaders (if all your libs use PSR-0 you have only one autoloader)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you use include or require, PHP is basically copy/pasting the code from the `required` file into your code. So no matter where you put it, PHP is still opening the file, reading it and dropping it in there, it won't be affected by an if block. In other words, require is parsed before the code is actually run, so yes, you will take a (very small) performance hit even if require is put in an if block and never run. Keep in mind, this is a very small impact. Lastly if you are worried about it, I would use `require_once` - this ensures that this parsing does not happen twice, for example if a second `required` file `requires` the first file, this redundancy won't amount to a second performance hit.

Comment: I dont think that it gets parsed if you use it in the conditional block. If I add some random characters in the file, then I get the parse error every time if the requires are on top, but if I put them in the if block, then I only get the errors if the condition is met

Comment: Little impact? Wouldn't making the hand dirty by accessing the file system (disc read) take longer?

Comment: Well yes the disk read will add a little overhead, but my answer presumed that the files were on the local filesystem (not mounted over the network), and on a modern system with at least a 1.5gbps SATA drive. Obviously running this on a system with a old ATA hard drive is going to take a significant performance hit. Morpha - correct, it won't be parsed, but it is still read and dropped in.